# GNU make confused by code generator

Tags: code-generation, makefile

I have a code generator (Python script generating C++) that takes a text file containing the glyphs of a simple bitmap font and generates .h and .cc files with the font's parameters and data.  The actuals of the generator are working fine; it's explaining this arrangement to GNU `make` that's giving me trouble.

The directory structure looks like:

```
project_dir/
    app/
        Foo/
            Makefile
            ... application source files ...
            gcc/
                ... all object files ...
    lib/
        LCD/
            Font_ProFont_10.txt
            ... library source files ...
```

My make rule looks like:

```
Font_%.cc Font_%.h: Font_%.txt $(GENFONT)
    @if [ 'x${VERBOSE}' = x ]; then echo "FONT(F) $<"; else \
        echo $(GENFONT) $<; fi
    @$(GENFONT) $<
```

Starting from a clean build (this is important), `make` will chug along fine on the sources until it hits a font, which dies with:

```
FONT(F) ../../lib/LCD/Font_ProFont_10.txt
  CXX   Font_ProFont_10.cc
arm-eabi-g++: Font_ProFont_10.cc: No such file or directory
arm-eabi-g++: no input files
make: *** [gcc/Font_ProFont_10.o] Error 1
```

Rerunning `make` will whitewash over this problem, since `make` will find the source file where it really is:

```
  CXX   ../../lib/LCD/Font_ProFont_10.cc
```

Since `Font_ProFont_10.cc` didn't exist when the build started, `make` gets the idea it would be generated into the current directory (project_dir/app/Foo/) instead of the library directory (which is where the rules says it will be, unless I'm missing something).

My key question is: **How do I change the make rule so make doesn't get confused?**

I don't want to put the generated files in with the distributed files, on principle, but I also would like `make` to complete successfully on a clean set of files.

I don't want to do this with recursion, because there are application-level configurations that need to be passed down to the libraries. So I'm generating all the objects into a directory in the application's directory.

**EDIT:** Changing to the following:

```
VPATH += ../../lib/LCD
LCD = ../../lib/LCD
# ...
$(LCD)/Font_%.cc $(LCD)/Font_%.h: Font_%.txt $(GENFONT)
    # ...
```

does not solve the problem:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `gcc/Font_Atmel_16.o', 
needed by `gcc/RTOSDemo.axf'.  Stop.
```

Here, `make` somehow doesn't know that you can make `gcc/Font_Atmel_16.o` from `../../lib/LCD/Font_Atmel_16.cc` using the `$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.c` rule, since `../../lib/LCD` is in `$(VPATH)`. It doesn't even run the `$(LCD)/Font_%.cc` rule.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble is that your `Font_%.cc` rule doesn't really build what it claims to build. If Make tries to use it to build `Font_ProFont_10.cc`, it expects to get `Font_ProFont_10.cc` (and plans accordingly), but what it actually gets is `../../lib/LCD/Font_ProFont_10.cc`. If `lib/LCD/` is where you want the generated files to go, then this

```
../../lib/LCD/Font_%.cc ../../lib/LCD/Font_%.h: Font_%.txt $(GENFONT)
    ...
```

will do exactly the same thing as your old rule, but Make will know what to expect. Just be sure your `%.o` rule looks for them there (so that it will know to invoke the rule above).

**EDIT:**
The above solution does work, but **you must make sure that the `%.o` rules looks for the generated files in the right place. VPATH will not suffice in this case.** If you want each generated file to go into the same directory as its source, and Make to know where they are for use as prerequisites -- and you really don't want to use recursion -- I can suggest two alternatives, both workable, neither perfect:

1. When you create Font_foo.cc somewhere, create a symbolic link to it in app/Foo/, and delete the link when Make is finished. (There's no need to retain the links for a future invocation of Make, since VPATH *will* find the files then.)

   Create tailored rules like the one above, one for each directory containing a %.txt file. **This can be done automatically, by Make,** with some careful use of "eval" and "call".

If one of these approaches sounds reasonable, I can lay it out in more detail.

Comment: This, of course, means that all the `Font_%.txt` files will need to be in a single directory.  So my question becomes **is there a way to tell `make` that the products will be in the same directory as the inputs?**  The obvious `$(<D)` doesn't work, and while your answer will work on this narrow case (since all these files are in the same directory), it won't for the more general case.  The `.o` rule will find the sources because `../../lib/LCD/` is in `$(VPATH)`. (And in case anyone is wondering, `%.cc %.h: %_font.txt $(GENFONT)` doesn't work either after renaming the sources; same error.)

Comment: P.S. Your fix didn't work (see above, edited question). Maybe the `.o` rule is ignoring `$(VPATH)`?

Comment: What's the difference between #2 and what I tried in my edit above? How does this tell the `%.o` rule where to look for the source?

Comment: Your edit does not contain a modified `%.o` rule. My option #2 involves making rules like `gcc/Font_%.o: ../../lib/LCD/Font_%.cc ...`.

Comment: Does the entire `%.o` rule need to be copied-and-pasted, or is there a way to make `$(OBJDIR)/Font_%.o: $(LCD)/Font_%.cc` call `$(OBJDIR)/Font_%.o: %.cc`?